# Why does my vim help open in this split window?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to read the vim manual in its own window but it opens in a split like this. How do I open the vim help file in fullscreen?

[image]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+help+window